# How to draw a 3D triangle using a VBO in OpenGL with LWJGL?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL, took me about 4 hours of hard work to achieve triangle rendering and VBOs. I want to render a triangle in 3D space. I know you have to use projection matrices but when I have a vertex array like this

```
float[] vertices = {
    -0.8, -0.8, -2.0,
    0, 0.8, -2.0,
    0.8, -0.8, -2.0
};
```

it doesn't render the triangle, but when I change the z values to -1 it renders. I have tried to implement projection matrices, but they manipulate the z axis which hides the triangle.

Also I use row major matrices, do I need column major? Because apparently rotation matrix works fine (row major).

I am using OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: Are you using an MVP matrix?

Comment: The default Z range is just like the X and Y range: -1 to +1. So, without further transformation, -2 is "off screen", clipped out of view. The default transformation just maps X and Y to your window, and clips Z -1 to +1. As an experiment to show this, make just one of the vertices Z = 0.0. You should then get a partial triangle.

Comment: @Ryan i am using a projection matrix

Comment: @Ryan but i think you mean model-view-projection, in that case no. No decent opengl tutoriala on lwjgl

Comment: @EEVV I haven't personally read it, but [this tutorial](http://forum.staticvoidgames.com/t/lwjgl-3-0-tutorial-modern-opengl-part-1/32) seems like it's what you need. LWJGL with more recent OpenGL

Comment: @Ryan i have seen this tutorial, mbut maybe i should look into it when im on pc, god... creating a graphics library is easier than this :(